# codeigniter 4 multiple file validation

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

i want to check the file is selected or not in controller if not selected then show error else upload on server. i create a html element like this  `<input type="file" name="car_gallery[]" multiple />` and my form has also this attribute enctype="multipart/form-data".
in controller i check like this

```
if($this->request->getFileMultiple('car_gallery')){
}
```

but this condition is always true even i did not select any file.
what is solution for multiple file upload its work fine on single image

Comment: did you try `var_dump($this->request->getFileMultiple('car_gallery'));` and see why it's marked true?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this either as I am having this problem too. But, I am logging (via `print_r`) the call to `$this->request->getFileMultiple('my_file_name_here')` and noticed when I submitted my form without having a file attached, a file object was created (hence returning TRUE - I think). The object has all the properties empty, except the `error` property is set to `4` and if this maps to [PHP's File Upload Errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), it means no file was uploaded.

I wonder if the object is created specifically because of this error?

Here is the code from my logging when I submit the form with no file attached.

```
(
    [0] => CodeIgniter\HTTP\Files\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [path:protected] => 
            [originalName:protected] => 
            [name:protected] => 
            [originalMimeType:protected] => 
            [error:protected] => 4
            [hasMoved:protected] => 
            [size:protected] => 0
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 
        )

)
```

I honestly don't know how to (or not to) check for an `if($this->request->getFileMultiple('my_file_name_here'))` if it is going to always be true whether a file is attached or not.

I could be totally wrong in all this. I am up for any help and suggestions.

If this is totally wrong or not in accord with the site rules, take it down by all means.

Answer (score -1):

Just use getFiles().

$this->request->getFiles('my_file_name_here')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).